# JQuery search filter code what step have I missed?

Tags: jquery, html

I have applied the steps from a tutorial to my own search bar for a photo gallery.  The aim is to have the search bar filter the images in real time, and show the image that matches that described in the search bar from the gallery. The first section of code works (the gallery hides when the search bar is written in) but the rest is not yet.  My html is structured with `<a>` tags and in the tutorial they did not.  I have tried adding these in the JQuery code, but no luck.  Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this?

```
<div id="photo-container" class="data-list">
     <ul>
        <li data-keywords="dry hill"><a href="Photos/01.jpg"><img     src="Photos/Thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Photo of a dry hill with blue skys.  This image was captured at the end of Summer in the region of Hawkes Bay." title="Dry Hill" class="photo photo1">
               </a></li>
             <li data-keywords="lake blue sky"><a href="Photos/02.jpg"><img src="Photos/Thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Photo of a lake with blue sky.  This image was taken in the mid morning of the Lakes District. " title="Lake" class="photo">
                 </a></li>
             <li data-keywords="green fields"><a href="Photos/03.jpg"><img src="Photos/Thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Green Fields is an image captured in the lush Southland area. " title="Photo Three" class="Green Fields">
                 </a></li>

     </ul>
    </div><!--closing photo-container-->
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#search").keyup(function(){

var current_query = $("#search").val();

if(current_query != ""){
 $("#photo-container").hide();

 $("#photo-container li").each(function(){

     var current_keyword = $(this).attr("data-keywords");

    if (current_keyword.indexOf(current_query) >=0) {
        $(this).show();
    } 
      });
} else {
        $("#photo-container li").show();
    }




 });  

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looking for all `<a>` elements and looking for their 'data-keywords' attributes but the 'data-keywords' attributes are on the `<li>` elements.

Either drop the `<a>` from the css selector in

```
$("#photo-container li a").each(function(){
```

or move the 'data-keywords' tags to the `<li>` elements.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I added the a, as I thought I might need it to get the image to show.  it did not work with $("#photo-container li ").each(function(){      .....do you think I need to alter this code to get it to locate the image   if (current_keyword.indexOf(current_query) >=0) {
                $(this).show();
            }

Comment: Looking again it might be better to change `var current_keyword = $(this).attr("data-keywords");` to `var current_keyword = $(this).parent().attr("data-keywords");`

Comment: ie: leave the attribute on the parent element and retrieve it from there.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this ago.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have got the search working!